# Wordpress already installed but asking to install

Tags: wordpress

I already installed wordpress and was setting up my site : i was customizing and it starts saying install wordpress when i reload page it shows like this . Even I have completed 90% of my site

and **its not first time** ! I'm facing this issue second time. first time when this happened I left it as it is and after a while I checked again and it was 
fine
[image: showing this]

Comment: make sure that the config file is named wp-config.php

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain why it starts working fine after some time.

Comment: I think this is permission issue read/write of wp-config.php.

Comment: Now its working fine ! I did nothing..........

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WordPress only redirects to install.php when it can not find a database. this missing database issue usually occurs because i have crappy host, ipage , they limited the mysql query string to 75k per hour and once that max usage is optimised, the site and every other WordPress site on that ipage user account starts redirecting to install.php

A way to combat this is to cache the mysql query string (but ipage has refused to do that – instead they have offered to increase the MySQL query limit to 150k queries per hour for an extra $36 and this will still not be sufficient for a busy site, especially during content upload or peak periods).

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/site-keeps-redirecting-to-installphp-over-and-over-again-1/

Comment: ``Crappy host`` This was my problem! I refreshed the website after 3 minutes and it was working fine

Comment: Yes, indeed that was the issue in my case at least. When I entered the PhPMyAdmin page it stated that I've exceeded my per hour query amount

Answer (score 11):

Check Your table prefix in wp-config.php and PhpMyadmin(database). Both are must be same

`$table_prefix  = 'wm_';`

Comment: I was struggling with this, I didn't check that after reading your post it hit in my mind. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Wordpress 5.1.1, and many other versions are the same

[image]

In table `wp-options`, you restore database from local, then must change when go to server.

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me just now and resulted in me googling this answer, the reason was that I had entered the GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES command incorrectly because HeidiSQL had automatically surrounded my asterisk with backticks when I was trying to grant privileges on all tables to the user that I had created for the site.  Make sure that you create your database user and grant privileges to them property, without backticks around your asterisk.